# Slave Taker and non-lethal sneak attacks

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The slave taker trait is as follows:

> **Slave Taker**
>   *Source:* Pirates of the Inner Sea pg. 9 ([Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1601254059))
>   *Category:* Region
>   *Requirement(s):* Okeno
>   You specialize in disabling foes without wounding them, preserving their value as slaves. Whenever you deal nonlethal damage in combat, that damage increases by +1.

Does non-lethal sneak attack damage count as a separate instance of damage in regards to this trait?

Answer (score 10):

**No**, as with normal sneak attack, it comes from the same source as the rest of the damage, even if the 'type' of damage is different (precision vs weapon).  Its why sneak attack isn't effected by DR separately.